# How to put trigonometric numbers as a power in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to make a graph with this function in *matlab* in space [-2,2]. Because I am new (really new actually) in *matlab*, I am struggling, especially with the first part of the function, the one with the *"e"*:

[image: see the attached image here]

So any help about the whole thing will be very useful.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. This will help you get more out of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Let's cover all the points in no particular order:

- The `e` is known as [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), where e ~ 2.71828...
  Something like e<sup>x</sup>, i.e. raising `e` to the power of `x` is known as the [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function). While you *could* in theory compute `e` and then use the `power` operator (`^` in matlab) to raise `e` to that power accordingly, this is in fact a less precise way of calculating the exponential function, and therefore matlab provides the `exp` function for that purpose. If you pass an array [x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>,...] to `exp`, it will perform this function "elementwise", and return [e<sup>x<sub>1</sub></sup>, e<sup>x<sub>2</sub></sup>,...] appropriately.
- The `sin` function, similarly, if given an array of numbers, will calculate the `sin` for each of those numbers, and return an array of the same shape as its input.
- You could use `fplot` with an anonymous function as Neo suggested, but I find that beginners find that confusing. So instead I would suggest you create an array of values between [-2,2], and obtain the value of y for each of them, which in matlab can be done as a single operation because it's good at working with arrays and performing such 'vectorized' operations:

  ```
  x = [-2:0.1:2];  % Create an array of values from -2 to 2, with a step of 0.1
                   % Note: the ';' at the end suppresses output; if you want to
                   % see the contents of your array, remove it at the end.
  ```
- Now that you have your array `x` you can perform operations on it. By convention, matlab uses "dot-operators" to denote "elementwise" operations, as opposed to 'undotted' ones denoting primarily "matrix" operations. Therefore to raise all elements of the array `x` to the power of 6, you would do `x .^ 6`
  With that in mind, you can now calculate your f(x) for each point in the array `x`, by using elementwise operations:

  ```
  y = exp( sin(x).^3 ) + x.^6 - 2*(x.^4) - x.^3 - 1;
  ```

  The result is an array `y` of the same size as `x`.
- You can now plot this using the `plot` command, which takes two arrays of the same size and plots all points in the first array against their equivalent points in the second array, as (x,y) pairs:

  ```
  plot( x, y );
  ```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, matlab 'connects' the points by default. If you wanted to see just the individual points of your array instead, you can specify this as the third argument:

```
plot(x, y, 'o');
```

[image]

Type `help plot` at the matlab terminal to see more options for the `plot` command.

---

<sub>PS: The above plots were made in octave rather than in matlab, because I don't have matlab at home. Your own plots may look slightly different.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

For a simple one-liner you could use:

```matlab
fplot(@(x) exp(sin(x).^3) + x.^6 - 2*x.^4 - x.^3 - 1, [-2 2]);
```

See [fplot](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html).